# jsRender pivot rows to columns - display data in columns

Tags: asp.net, pivot, jsrender, jsviews

I'm using jsRender and I wanted to display my data as columns rather then the rows I am returning. I want to pivot the data - is this something that can be done with jsRender. I can't get the data pivoted in SQL so my only option is to do it myself.

This is basically what I am after. I want to write the column names myself.

---

Header | Row 1 | Row 2 | Row 3 |

---

Column Blah | Row data | Row data | Row data

---

More blah | Row data | Row data | Row data

---

I have tried to use the {{for}} loop for table cell but I just don't know where to start.

**UPDATE:**
After Boris's suggestion I have tried the suggested code. Although I as it's not formatting properly I have included it here.

This is an excerpt of my JSON source:

```
{
  "Layers": {
    "Layer": [
      {
    "@LayerID": "1",
    "RiskRef": {
      "@ColVal": "Contract/Section Number",
      "#text": "PUSNA11000392/1"
    },
    "ContractStatus": {
      "@ColVal": "New, Renewal or NTU?",
      "#text": "New"
    },
    "AdjustRate": {
      "@ColVal": "Adjustable Rate",
      "#text": "0.53%"
    },
```

And my jsRender javaScript code is:

```
<script id="xolDetailsTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
            {{for Layers}}
                {{for >#data["Layer"]}}
                <td>{{>#data["@LayerID"]}}</td>
                {{/for}}
            {{/for}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is 
`model = { people: [{firstName: "Jo", lastName: "Colby"}, ...] }`

you can use the following template to render a people array, pivoted rows to columns:

```
<tbody>
    <tr><td>First Name</td>{{for people}}<td>{{>firstName}}</td>{{/for}}</tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name</td>{{for people}}<td>{{>lastName}}</td>{{/for}}</tr>
</tbody>
```

In your comment below you say that your data is has field names like "@foo". Lets consider this example:
`model = { "people": [{"@firstName": "Jo", "@lastName": "Colby"}}, ...] }`.

You can render this with a template as follows:

```
<tbody>
    <tr><td>First Name</td>{{for people}}<td>{{>#data["@firstName"]}}</td>{{/for}}</tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name</td>{{for people}}<td>{{>#data["@lastName"]}}</td>{{/for}}</tr>
</tbody>
```

If the field name has non JavaScript name characters, such as "@" that is where you need to use the syntax `#data["@xxx"]`.

Comment: I thought that would be the case. However my source is XML from a SQL Server database which has attributes. When I convert the XML to a JSON string I have everything in quotes. So my attributes are "@LayerNo"

Comment: Here's a snippet of my JSON string. 

"MyData": {
    "Row": [
      {
        "@RowID": "1",
        "Column1": {
          "@ColVal": "Contract/Section Number",
          "#text": "PUSNA11000392/1"
        },
        "Column2": {
          "@ColVal": "New, Renewal or NTU?",
          "#text": "New"
        },

Comment: Ah, you had not said that in the original question. Answer updated to help you deal with those special characters...

Comment: Apologies Boris. Thanks for the update. I will have a go. As you can imagine I've been trying out other solutions so I'm flicking between different methods at the mo. I will mark this as answered - hope to test this out soon. Thank you again for your help :-)

Comment: @ArminderDahul - I see you never marked this reply as 'accepted'. Could be good to do so...

Comment: Apologies, I thought I did. Better late than never.